# How to use keySet().iterator() to find patterns in keys in a HashMap

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have crated an HashMap and keyset Iterartor as follows:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap< Integer,String>();**

map.put(-1505711364, "4");
map.put(294357273, "15");
map.put(-1593134417, "28");
map.put(-1231165758, "45");     
map.put(121046798, "58");
map.put(294357273, "71");
map.put(-1593134417, "82");
map.put(-1231165758, "95");
map.put(121046798, "108");

Iterator<Integer> keySetIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
```

I need to extract `15,28,45` & `71,82,95` as they are having same pattern of keys. Likewise i need to find of various common patterns from size 2 onwards.

How can i do this using keySetIterator?

Comment: You do realize subsequent `put` calls with the same key **overwrites** the previous entries, right? When you put 71, it overwrites 15. There's no way to get that value back. I think you need to study more about what a `Map` is.

Comment: maybe you want a multimap?

Answer (score 3):

If you run `map.put()` twice with the same key, it will *overwrite* the previous entry.  This is because a fundamental assumption is that keys in a `Map` are unique and so only one of each key can be present.